# Where do I set transaction protocol?

Tags: web-services, wcf, transactions

I have set up a sample WCF service with transactions that use Transaction Flow - it builds and seems to be running as far as the debug client is concerned.

I know that, as of .NET Framework 4, there are two different transaction protocols in Windows Communication Foundation:

- OLETransactions Protocol
- WS-AtomicTransaction Protocol

However, I have no idea how to configure my service to use either of these, and which protocol my service is using by default. So - how do I do that?

### Obligatory *"show your work"* part of the post

[According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733116(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0), I should probably set that at binding level, but the `<binding>` element

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="transactionBinding" transactionFlow="true" />
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

doesn't seem to have any protocol-related attribute.

I also searched for relevant annotations to use along with `[ServiceContract]` or `[OperationContract]`, but I couldn't find any, either.

All my attempts at Googling gave me MSDN I already read and loads of copy-pasted programming tutorials parroting each other that all talk about how there are two protocols without any mention how to actually set them up.

I suspect that by using `<wsHttpBinding>` I am using WS-Atomic, but there's no mention of WS-Atomic in [a relevant MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731299(v=vs.110).aspx). Even if that turned out to be true, I still wouldn't know how to switch to OLE.